# Mpldatacursor issue in Anaconda python?

Tags: python

I am also new to python.Just started learning how to make simple plot in python.I am anaconda spyder.Today I also came to know how to see installed packages and update ,delete etc using conda. In my command prompt I have seen mpldatacursor availability. But I try to use it in my simple plot code it is showing error.it says it can not import datacursor. I am trying to get the solution for last one week. Please advise. Thanks .

Comment: from mpldatacursor import datacursor
ImportError: cannot import name datacursor

Comment: Anybody please suggest.